# fast floating point multiplication

Tags: floating-point, embedded

I am working in an embedded platform and need to a faster way to do floating point multiplications for some algorthims.  Does anyone know of a fast implementation, I can give up some precision for speed.

Comment: Which platform?  What features does it have?  Why not just use the hardware's floating-point multiply?

Comment: why not use fixed point and manage the decimal yourself?  that is all floating point is anyway.

Comment: Not enough information. Do you need full IEEE754 behaviour? i.e., do you have to deal with NaNs, INFs, denormals, etc.? Or can you manage with fixed-point mantissa multiplications, and *additive* `(2^EXP)`?

Comment: Processor and tool chain?

Answer (score 1):

If your target has an FPU then it will already perform floating point multiplication as fast as it possibly can.  If however it does not have an FPU, then you are better off using fixed point arithmetic instead.

Using fixed point arithmetic in C is complicated by the fact that there is no built-in fixed point data type - every operation is an explicit function call, which is not very natural or readable, in C++ however it is possible to define a `fixed` class with operator and function overloading such that using fixed point is simply a case of replacing `float` or `double` with `fixed`, including automatic conversions between types.  One such library, that includes a comprehensive math library and not just simple arithmetic operators can be found [here](http://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/news/optimizing-applications-with-fixed-point-arithmetic.html).  On ARM it is typically 5 times faster than software floating point.

If using C++ code worries you, you can in most cases use C++ compilation to support the fixed point library but essentially write C code as if it had a built-in `fixed` type.  That is to say, you do not need to use or know much C++ to benefit from this library, and there will be no overhead over the same code compiled as C.

Comment: `If your target has an FPU then it will already perform floating point multiplication as fast as it possibly can`  @Clifford - I'm confident you know this, but OP might not be... even if the target has an FPU, unless the build environment is configured to use the on-chip FPU, and unless the FPU is enabled, the code will still use S/W emulation.  Believe me, I see this all the time...

Comment: @Dan:  A very good point.  A few years ago, I evaluated an LPC3180; and unusual ARM9+VFP chip, even when configured to use the FPU, the library implementation of sqrt() still used a convergence algorithm rather than the hardware sqrt instruction.  It took some figuring out to get the correct library to link.